# KnockOut Binding issue in IE11

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js

I have a KnockOut view model as

```
viewModel = {
    // Observables
    insuredPersonList: ko.observableArray(),
    premiumFrequency: ko.observable(initialData.premiumFrequency),
    monthlyType: ko.observable(getMonthlyTypeFromInitialData()),
    includeCareClause: ko.observable(initialData.includeCareClause),
    nrOfInsuredChildren: ko.observable(initialData.nrOfInsuredChildren),
    hasValidResponse: ko.observable(false),
    currentCalculations: ko.observable(0),
    firstname: ko.observable(initialData.firstname),
    lastname: ko.observable(initialData.lastname),
    email: ko.observable(initialData.email),
    birthday: ko.observable(initialData.birthday),
    producerAccount: ko.observable(initialData.producerAccount),
    delaSiteType: ko.observable(initialData.delaSiteType),
    userid: ko.observable(initialData.userid),
    language: ko.observable(initialData.language)
}
```

And in one part of the code I'm trying to bind the value of the text box to the observable. The problem is that it works in IE 8,9,10, Chrome, Firefox but not in IE11.

```
<asp:TextBox CssClass="inputfield M numbersOnly" runat="server" ID="txtPremiumInsured1" 
data-bind="value: insuredPersonList()[0].premium, enable: monthlyType() == 'premium'" />
```

Comment: By look it should work fine . can you share us any specific error you see in console .

Comment: There is no error in console. It just doesn't bind the value. the value of the insuredPersonList()[0].premium is always 0 in IE11

Comment: This is both too much and too little code. Write a fiddle that just creates the `insuredPersonList` with data like you have in your program, and binds `insuredPersonList()[0].premium` to something.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Why don't you remove all the properties that are not used in your viewmodel sample, and include the missing definition of insuredPersonList objects? Please, read this: http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve